# How to add library for BouncyCastleProvider Security

Tags: java, security

I am confuse where add jar file (bcprov-jdk15-145.jar) for adding security file for BouncyCastleProvider. In application library or In JRE jre6\lib\ext\ folder.

```
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a specific reason for adding a JAR file to the JRE's `lib/ext` directory don't put anything in there.  This directory is for [Installed Extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html), not just dependencies of your application.

Just add the `bcprov-jdk15-145.jar` file to the Classpath of your application.

Comment: In other application this file is added in lib/ext folder, so i am confused that is there any specific reason to add this .jar file into lib/ext folder.

Comment: THis was necessary with Java 1.3 and 1.4 but is no longer required. http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html#install

Answer (score 1):

The generic answer would be: "On the classpath". Most often that would be with your application, eg. within an EAR or WAR file.

Cheers,